# Symlinking multiple files at once?

Tags: windows-10, powershell, cmd.exe, symbolic-link

*On Windows 10, how do I symlink several files at once?*

On Linux it’s easy:

```
ln -s source/directory/* destination/directory/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows has no equivalent command. You could use a `.bat` file similar to this:

```
@echo off
for /f %%f in ('dir /b "C:\path\to\source\directory"') do (
    mklink "C:\path\to\destination\directory\%%f" "C:\path\to\source\directory\%%f"
)
```

Comment: Windows shell is painful. Guess I’m back to [Link Shell Extension](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/linkshellextension.html).